Google SSO login issue
The error [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] Unexpected token '<', "<DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON indicated that an API response is returning HTML instead of JSON. This typically happens when the API request is not being handled correctly and instead returns an HTML page (such as index.html) that starts with
File Name / path : \pages\api\auth\[...nextauth].ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import axios from 'axios';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  // pages: {
  //   signIn: '/login', // Custom sign-in page if needed
  // },


  pages: {
    signIn: '/login', // Custom sign-in page
    error: '/auth/error', // Custom error page
  },


  session: {
    maxAge: 30 * 60, // Session expires in 2 minutes (120 seconds)
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      try {
        // Validate access token with Google API
        const response = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=${token.accessToken}`);


        console.log('Google Session')

        console.log(response);

        // return;


        if (response.status !== 200) {
          throw new Error('Invalid token'); 
        }
        // session.user.email = token.email;
      } catch (error) {
        // If the token is invalid, return null or handle session invalidation
        // session;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
});

Resetting my GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID and GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, and NEXTAUTH_SECRET
Adding "secret: NEXTAUTH_SECRET" as an option above providers to my [...nextauth].ts file, even though according to the docs it is not needed
Inputting localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google directly into the URL, which worked and I was able to access my session object in my homepage. It sent me here OAuth Page
Updated next-auth from 4.14.0 to 4.15.0
Cleared cookies and sessions from http://localhost:3000
